# user access level in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, dreamweaver

my problem is maybe just a simple problem to you whom expert, but i still cant understand where to put this loop code

where should i put this :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($row['level']==1)
    {
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
    else if($row['level']==2)
    {
        header('Location: home2.php');
    }
    else if($row['level']==3)
    {
        header('Location: home3.php');
    }

}
```

in this :

```
`<?php
session_start();
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$katalaluan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['katalaluan']);


mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
mysql_select_db("sistem_laporan") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from profil WHERE id='$id'"); //Query the profil table if there are matching rows equal to $id
$exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if id exists
$table_profil = "";
$table_katalaluan = "";

if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing id
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
    {
        $table_profil = $row['id']; // the first id row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished
        $table_katalaluan = $row['katalaluan']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished


    }
    if(($id == $table_profil) && ($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)) // checks if there are any matching fields
    {
            if($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)
            {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id; //set the id in a session. This serves as a global variable

                header("location: home.php"); // redirects the user to the authenticated home page

            }

    }
    else
    {
        Print '<script>alert("Kata Laluan dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
    }

}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("ID Pengguna dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
    Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
}
?>`
```

the main thing is i want redirect different level(1-admin 2-assistant 3-director) to different page but i didnt know where to put that while loop in the main code WITHOUT changing the structure of main code.hope someone can help me. sorry for bad english.thanks.

Comment: Your code already contains a loop that loops over the results, so I would put the contents of the loop(but not the loop itself) inside the existing one. One more thing you should take a look at either mysqli or PDO for the db connection and look at prepared statements, they are safer.

Comment: @furrie i tried to replace this while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($row['level']==1)
    {
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
    else if($row['level']==2)
    {
        header('Location: home2.php');
    }
    else if($row['level']==3)
    {
        header('Location: home3.php');
    }

}

at header("location: home.php"); in main but it redirect to empty blank page

Comment: Are you sure the level field contains a value between 1 and 3? And that you haven't done some output before the current code?

Comment: @furrie im sure..there is a form that ask admin to enter level..it is only 2 and 3 in dropdown menu..level 1 is for admin which is i manually inserted in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the while loop to identify the user type since it already exist. You just have to add the conditional statements under *if($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)*

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
mysql_select_db("sistem_laporan") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from profil WHERE id='$id'"); //Query the profil table if there are matching rows equal to $id
$exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if id exists
$table_profil = "";
$table_katalaluan = "";

if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing id
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
    {
        $table_profil = $row['id']; // the first id row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished
        $table_katalaluan = $row['katalaluan']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished


    }
    if(($id == $table_profil) && ($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)) // checks if there are any matching fields
    {
            if($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)
            {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id; //set the id in a session. This serves as a global variable

                if($row['level']==1)
                    {
                        header('Location: home.php');
                    }
                    else if($row['level']==2)
                    {
                        header('Location: home2.php');
                    }
                    else if($row['level']==3)
                    {
                        header('Location: home3.php');
                    }

            }

    }
    else
    {
        Print '<script>alert("Kata Laluan dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
        Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
    }

}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("ID Pengguna dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
    Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
}
```

Comment: i just tried the code you corrected but it redirect to empty blank page(checklogin.php)

Comment: @hicarl instead of just using home.php, try using the complete url.

Answer (score 0):

I try @ikeMiguel code and no got error

you say got empty blank page (checklogin.php)
is that the code of checklogin.php?

maybe you must get value from $id variable
add

> **$id = $_POST['id'];**

under mysql_select_db

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
mysql_select_db("sistem_laporan") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect database
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from profil WHERE id='$id'"); //Query the profil table if there are matching rows equal to $id
$exists = mysql_num_rows($query); //Checks if id exists
$table_profil = "";
$table_katalaluan = "";



if($exists > 0) //IF there are no returning rows or no existing id
  {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //display all rows from query
    {
        $table_profil = $row['id']; // the first id row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished
        $table_katalaluan = $row['katalaluan']; // the first password row is passed on to $table_profil, and so on until the query is finished


}
if(($id == $table_profil) && ($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)) // checks if there are any matching fields
{
        if($katalaluan == $table_katalaluan)
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id; //set the id in a session. This serves as a global variable

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
           {
             if($row['level']==1)
             {
              header('Location: home.php');
             }
             else if($row['level']==2)
             {
              header('Location: home2.php');
             }
             else if($row['level']==3)
             { 
              header('Location: home3.php');
             }

           }

        }

}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("Kata Laluan dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
    Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
}


}
     else
     {
         Print '<script>alert("ID Pengguna dimasukkan adalah salah!");</script>'; //Prompts the user
         Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>'; // redirects to login.php
     }
```

Comment: i edited the session part on top of the code. feel free to view the code again. for your information this is the checklogin.php...before this page there is a login.php